# How to alias my domain's subdomain with my jelastic environment subdomain?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, jelastic

I have a kubernetes cluster hosted on a Jelastic environment `env.jelastic-provider.com`. In that k8s cluster, I am exposing a frontend app on `app.env.jelastic-provider.com`. I would like to use a CNAME record to alias my custom domain `www.example.com` to the frontend subdomain `app.env.jelastic-provider.com`. How can I achieve that? My DNS provider does not propose ANAME records.

Currently, I have defined a CNAME record aliasing `www.example.com` to `app.env.jelastic-provider.com` on my dns provider. On the Jelastic side, I've bound `www.example.com` to `env.jelastic-provider.com` with the `jelastic.environment.Binder.BindExtDomain` api method, which of course doesn't work, because I'd need to bind to `app.env.jelastic-provider.com`, which does not seem to be possible.

Do I have a way out not involving:

- serving my frontend e.g. through CDN instead of my cluster
- using ANAME record

?

## Edit

Following the advice of Jelastic and of my Jelastic provider, I was able to make some good progress. Today, it turns out attaching external IPs to the k8s cluster worker nodes is not supported yet. It will come in a later release of the [jelastic kubernetes jps](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/kubernetes). We can see in that manifest that most of the configuration is there, just the attachment of the IP to the worker nodes isn't done, as it is pretty involved.

Therefore, the only solution I am left with, according to [this answer from Jelastic](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/kubernetes/issues/27#issuecomment-601699615_), is that I add an nginx load-balancer in front of my k8s cluster and configure the dns for it. To do so, I need to configure SSL on that nginx instance, as the cluster will not work correctly without https. So the first steps are

1. Add nginx node in front of the cluster
2. Install let's encrypt addon on the nginx node
3. Configure an A record on my domain provider panel, where I link the IPv4 address resulting from the previous let's encrypt installation with `www.example.com`
4. When the A record is valid, update the let's encrypt addon so that it takes the domain into account.

Also, I got rid of my domain bindings, as they are useless with A records.

If I do all that, then I can again access a working k8s cluster. The kubernetes dashboard as well as the kubernetes api are working.

What is, however, not working, is the access to my cluster's subdomains. As I stated in my original post, I need to access `app.env.jelastic-provider.com`. This is where I am now stuck. How can I now access that subdomain?

Comment: Currently, there is no such possibility to implement the requested functionality. The limitation affects any clustered solution.

Comment: Hmmm. Then I guess my only remaining choice is to host my k8s cluster on GKE or Azure??? Is it at least working with ANAME records? maybe I'll switch domain provider ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, long story short. After the initial configuration mentioned in the edit of my initial post,

> 1. Add nginx node in front of the cluster
> 2. Install let's encrypt addon on the nginx node
> 3. Configure an A record on my domain provider panel, where I link the IPv4 address resulting from the previous let's encrypt installation with www.example.com
> 4. When the A record is valid, update the let's encrypt addon so that it takes the domain into account.

the address `https://www.example.com` leads to my cluster back again, with working k8s dashboard and api. Then,

1. in my domain provider, I've added another A record for `app.env.jelastic-provider.com` pointing to the IPv4 of the nginx load-balancer with name `app`
2. in the let's encrypt configuration of the nginx load-balancer, I've added the `app.example.com` external domain
3. in the `nginx-jelastic.conf` file, I've added

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  app.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://app.env.jelastic-provider.com;
    }
}
```

4. in the `ssl.conf`, I've added

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name app.example.com;
  ssl_certificate      /var/lib/jelastic/SSL/jelastic.chain;
  ssl_certificate_key  /var/lib/jelastic/SSL/jelastic.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app.env.jelastic-provider.com;
  }
}
```

Of course, the above SSL config is not perfect, it must be tuned for production purposes.

### EDIT

I noticed there is one downside to this way of proceeding with the frontal nginx load-balancer. Whatever headers / config you set in the load-balancer will be somehow overriden by the cluster's own ingress controller. If you go down this way, make sure both configs are kept consistent...

Answer (score 0):

Usage of CNAME together with Public IP the only way out you are looking for.

[Custom Domain Name](https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-domains)

[Public IP](https://docs.jelastic.com/public-ip)

Comment: So you advocate to have an nginx load balancer in front of the cluster with a public IP, is that correct? The problem with that solution is that my subdomains are not recognized anymore. Any hint on the nginx config I could use to make the subdomains reachable again?

Comment: Also, what domain binding do I have to do? `www.mydomain.com` with `env.jelastic-provider.com` or `domain.com` with `env.jelastic-provider.com`?

Comment: And btw the documentation you provide in your answer on custom domain names tells that I should use A record with public IP.

Comment: After some googling, I stumbled upon [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/377934/can-i-use-cname-with-ip-address-why-if-works-sometimes) (just for an example). In fact, it makes no sense to use a CNAME together with a public IP.